# Bitcoin-cli Wallet creation error: Could not locate rpc credentials

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm installing an application on my vps for testing. The updated version of the bitcoin core doesnt create wallets automatically as it used to. hence i'm running into some problems i haven't dealt with before (i'm not very experienced with bitcoin core in general). If anyone could help me out, i will appreciate it

Here are some logs:

-After running a script that checks everything is set correctly including btc wallet, the following error is displayed:

```
>     File"/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bitcoin/rpc.py", line 239, in _call 'message': err.get('message', 'error message not specified')})
>     bitcoin.rpc.JSONRPCError: ['code': -18, 'message': 'No wallet is loaded. Load a wallet using loadwallet or create a new one with createwallet.
 (Note: A default is no longer automatically created)'}
```

And this error occurs when i try to create a wallet:
*bitcoin-cli createwallet user1*

```
>     error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and RPC password is not set. See -rpcpassword and
> -stdinrpcpass. Configuration file: (/root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)
```

I tried to counter it with the following command:
*bitcoin-cli rpcuser=user rpcpassword=password createwallet user1

I get the same error as above.